# Achieve fork-safety for C++ programs

Tags: python, c++, fork

I'm an infra engineer, whose main programming language is C++. I expose interface to Python users via [pybinder](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). One of my headache derives from: threads in Python don't support parallelism via multi-threading (because of GIL), so have to achieve parallelism by fork/multi-processing, which breaks my program.

I want to know what should I do to achieve fork-safety? Several things I have tried:

1. spawn new threads after fork, by [atfork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_atfork.3.html).
2. close all file descriptors inherited in child process, which are inherited from parent process, and re-open them in the child process. This is also achieve by fork-hook.

But I cannot make my program fork-safe, a concrete example is: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/ephiperfifo.html

I want to know, what else should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks my program"?

Comment: it means, libcurl no longer proceeds IO, the whole program gets stuck

Comment: I have had similar issues in the past with wanting to fork from a function that is called from the JVM and came to the conclusion that there isn't really a robust way to do it. But you may be working from a somewhat false premise. You can support parallelism in a C++ library that is used by python by trying to avoid holding the GIL except when it is absolutely necessary. A lot of libraries do this quite successfully.

Comment: Are you maybe forking while holding some lock?

Comment: > Are you maybe forking while holding some lock? The procedure works in the order of "first IO to read some data, then python use multi-processing to do training". Of course, there could be some other IO within training process to dump/read data. In theory, fork only happens when the first part of IO completes. So shouldn't hold some locks.

Comment: @TimSeguine Are you suggesting me to release GIL in the pybinder?

Comment: @Dentiny Yes and no. That is one way to do it. But even if your c++ library holds the GIL, it is perfectly acceptable for it to have it's own threads(that exploit full parallelism) as long as it handles its own synchronization.

Comment: Let me put it another way: lets say you want to use a library that isn't threadsafe in a C++ program. Does that mean suddenly that program can't utilize parallelism? No. It only means your interaction with that library is single threaded. The same thing is true with python bindings. Your interaction with the python interpreter is single threaded effectively by virtue of the GIL. But that in no way inhibits you from exploiting parallelism on your own for data structures you construct outside of direct control of the python interpreter.